# Layout with Tables - Hierarchy

Tags: website-design, page-layout, css, html

In this fiddle there's a markup and style I'm doing for a website:

http://jsfiddle.net/UvJmP/

I am trying to represent data in this way:

- D2's table data is contained in D1
- D3's table data is contained in D2

If we were to think of D1 as an entity, it would be said that each D1 has a D2, and each D2 has a D3. In a hierarchy, these would be "sub-tables."

Is there a better way to represent a hierarchy of subtables than the stair arrangement I have right now?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit because I realize that English is not your first language. Are you asking "How do I describe the relationships between D1 and D2, and D2 and D3"? Or "How do I visually represent those relationships"?

Comment: Ok, yes, my english is not that proper. Sorry for that.
And yes, I'm asking just that. How do I represent those relationships? Other than putting the tables on a stair-like form.

Comment: I have edited your post into clearer English (no apologies necessary :) ). Did I understand you correctly? Feel free to roll back anything I have misinterpreted.

Comment: Yes, It is ok like that. Thank you, by the way. So, if you know of any way to represent it other like that stair arrangement, please let me know. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a usability point of view, the staircase or indentation layout is probably better, because it's quite easy to see the difference in the levels just at a glance. I like the option of colors too, but I think it's a little more difficult to see.

Here's how I'd recommend to do it, specially if you can collapse some of the sub-tables:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solutions seems good, but your comment has given me a lot to think about. Thanks =)

Answer (score 3):

A little color coding might simplify the presentation for you. Sometimes all that extra indenting just makes things more confusing.

I also made subtle adjustments to the type style of each header to reinforce the hierarchy.

[image]